# support(x) function

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a `matlab` function that finds the support of a *fuzzy set*.

First, to know what `support(x)` means, it is: a crisp set that contains elements with degree of membership > 0

An example of a membership function is [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/fuzzy/trapmf.html).

For example, if I run the following commands in matlab (note that trapmf is part of the fuzzy logic toolbox just in case it doesn't run with you)

```
>> x=1:5

x =

     1     2     3     4     5

>> y=trapmf(x,[1 3 4 5]);
>> y

y =

         0    0.5000    1.0000    1.0000         0
```

So, `support(x)` here will be: `2,3,4`, since those are the elements that had a nonzero membership value.

Having got this idea, I tried to do that as a matlab function (.m file) as follows:

```
function support(x)
   y = trapmf(x,[1 3 4 5]);
for i=1:length(y)
    if(y(i) == 0)
        x(i)
    end   
end
```

But, when I run it, I get the following:

```
>> support(x)

ans =

     1


ans =

     5
```

Why is that? What should I fix in the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your code is doing, but how about just using this:

```
function s = support(x)
   y = trapmf(x,[1 3 4 5]);
   s = x(y~=0)
```

Comment: You may want to specify a second input argument to allow [1 3 4 5] to be variable.